# What is the extra wire for in my ceiling fan junction box?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I open the box on the ceiling and there were 3 wires,white,black,red as well as a ground. The fan will be on a switch not a three way. What is the red wire for? Also with switch off the white and red had power with my tester but not the black.

Comment: did the black have power with the switch on?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Answer (score 2):

Normally that type of wiring at the ceiling box would be a white neutral, an always hot black wire and a red switched hot, would become hot when a switch was turned on and a ground. This is wired this way so a fan light could be operated by a switch and the fan operated by the fan pull chain, but it doesn't have to be like that.

This could have been reversed in your case if your reading are correct: a white neutral, an always hot red and a switched hot black.
Check all your reading again to verify what you've got up there.

Comment: In my area both hots would be switched--one for the fan and one for the light.

Answer (score 1):

3-core cable has lots of uses.  It all is manufactured black white red.

The uses on a fan/light are allow separate switching or control of the fan and light, so you aren't *forced* to turn them on *together*.

Keep in mind both building and electrical codes **require** that there a switch in the room in the usual location (which is how you can find a light in a hotel room or other room you've never been in before), and that switch must operate a light.  Often this is done by having "the light that is on the fan" be *the* main light in the room, and that would suck if there wasn't separate fan control.  Hence the extra wire.

Comment: "and that would suck if there wasn't separate fan control" the reality all too often :(

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. If the line cable enters in the switch box, a proper cable from a wall switch box to the ceiling fan box would have separate switched hots, black and red, for the fan and a light fixture. There would be two switches in the wall, one for the fan and one for the light. This would be a /3 cable and the white would be a common neutral used by both fan and light.

A builder who had originally installed only a ceiling light fixture (no fan) and a single gang box could install a /3 cable to allow easy upgrading to a fan/light combo. Originally the red or the black in the /3 cable would be unconnected.

2. If the line cable enters in the ceiling box a /3 cable would be used to take neutral to the switch box as now required. The black and the red would be line hot and switched hot, respectively.

A /4 cable to the switch box would be required to separately control a fan and a light if the white is used to take neutral to the switch box.

Which do you have, 1 or 2? How many separate cables are in the ceiling box and how many in the wall box?